# Rails action is calling only once, but i call it every second in my ajax

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, coffeescript

Title is incorrect, but you might understand it.
I have this code in .coffee:

```
 $.ajax(url: "/get_current_result_number").done (html) ->
    $("#results").append html
    setInterval( $.ajax, 1000 )
```

And in the controller:

```
def get_current_result_number
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { render :xml => "<progress value=#{$status[:current]} max=#{$status[:all]} ></progress>" }
  end
end
```

Global variable $status has data for progresbar, and i want to see it in real time, without refresh page. I see requests in rails console permanently. Action get_current_result_number is call only one, with first request, and dont call with next.
Where is error? (in code, not in English))

Comment: In which .coffee file ? In which controller ?

Comment: yes, in /assets/javascripts/mainpage.coffee . I see requests in server console
But code in get_current_result_number action is run only once

Comment: call ajax inside setInterval, not in ajax. `setInterval($ajax_function here, 1000);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$.ajax` is not your defined ajax call. You can rewrite it like this:

```
getCurrentResults = ()->
  $.ajax(url: "/get_current_result_number").done (html) ->
    $("#results").append html

setInterval(getCurrentResults, 1000)
```